# GPS Active vs Passive SMD antenna

Tags: antenna, surface-mount, gps

I'm designing a tiny wearable device that is characterized by a plastic case. It contains the PCB and the battery (Lipo).

I'm struggling a lot with the GPS antenna because I must use a small SMD antenna. At the moment I performed a lot of different tests using various types of antennas (some examples, Antenova, Ignion, Pulse Larsen, Molex etc...).
The GPS module used is a NEO-M9N from Ublox.
I tested the antenna using small and dedicated PCBs. For example, I bought this which was very helpful (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15247).
I found out that the best antenna, despite being the smallest one, was the  Pulse Larsen W3011 (https://productfinder.pulseelectronics.com/product/w3011). I achieved great results with it!
[image]

**Now the problem:**
due to the super tiny dimension, the antenna feed pin is shorted with the ground pin. That's pretty common on very small antennas.

I noticed that **if I'm using the antenna in the passive configuration** (no external supply coming from the Ublox GPS module) the antenna took ages to get a fix, after that the antenna is working well.
**If I'm supplying the antenna with the 3V coming** from the Ublox GPS module (like if it's active), the antenna is definitely faster in order to get a fix and it's working better (more accurate I'd say).
Why that is happening?
Of course, the current limiting resistor R23 gets extremely hot and the power consumption of the entire board is x3 respecting the normal. It makes total sense because it's creating a short between the feed pin and ground.
[image]

I did a similar test using the Ignion NN03-320 (https://www.google.com/search?q=nn03-320&oq=NN0&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j35i19i39l2j0i512l2j0i30l5.2203j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) antenna using the original dev-board from them. If I'm using this antenna in passive configuration (as it should be) I got the same problems (ages to fix and not super performances), while if I'm using it as an active antenna everything is working more than great. (More than that, this antenna is not absorbing extra current because there's a series capacitor on the evaluation board that is blocking the supply coming from the Ublox M9N).
[image]

**My questions are:**

- Why I'm experiencing this behavior on the W3011 antenna?
- What's the role of the series capacitor and why it's blocking the current draw? (With this I got high performances and no current draw).
- How can I use one small SMD antenna in an "active" configuration without the extra current draw? (I already increased the resistance of the current limiting resistor but I think it's not the right thing to do. Or maybe I can add a series capacitor that will not affect the transmission with the Pulse Larsen W3011?)

Sorry for the long text, but I tried to be as complete as possible.
Many thanks in advance for your time.
Cheers
Enry

Comment: Passive antennas should not work better with DC bias added, especially those that are a DC short! Instead, I think your test results are explained by the sequence of your testing. During the first, passive mode test, the GPS module acquired the satellites and downloaded the associated orbital data. During your second, active test, the GPS module can re-use the existing data so a fix is faster. Try reversing the order of your testing.

Comment: Hello @MarkLeavitt, thanks for your prompt reply.
I did the test in cold-fix configuration for both setups. Basically, by powering off the GPS module (and without the backup battery supply connected) I can make a new cold-fix at any time.

While in hot-fix, it takes seconds.

It's also strange that the W3011 antenna has not a dedicated matched circuit in the datasheet, just a shunt capacitor.

Comment: Are you sure you're not inadvertently disabling/enabling any LNA/filter front end when you switch between your passive and "active" configuration? Software/firmware error?

Comment: Hu @MarkLeavitt, 100% same firmware.
Just removing one component (L3) with hot air in order to open the supply line to the antenna.

Comment: Can you add a photo of the W3011 PCB with the antenna and matching / feed components? With a ruler next to it.  E.g., an open stub of 1/4 wave (allowing for velocity factor) would look like a short at the other end.